# rtl8192ce Drivers not compiling in Raring

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 13.04, rtl8192ce

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.0.4 Raring Ringtail onto my HP Pavilion G6, and I am having trouble compiling the drivers for my rtl8192ce wi-fi adapter.  I've been searching around for a few days now and I haven't had any luck.

The driver I'm attempting to compile and install is here:

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57056576/DRIVERS/REALTEK/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012.tar.gz

Here's the error I'm receiving when I attempt to run the "make" command:

make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build M=/home/addison/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/addison/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o
In file included from /home/addison/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:39:0:
/home/addison/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/pci.h:245:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl_pci_probe’
/home/addison/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/home/addison/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: error: ‘IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/addison/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/addison/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In function ‘rtl_action_proc’:
/home/addison/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:870:25: error: ‘RX_FLAG_MACTIME_MPDU’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/addison/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In function ‘rtl_send_smps_action’:
/home/addison/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:1432:16: error: ‘struct <anonymous>’ has no member named ‘sta’
make[2]: *** [/home/addison/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/addison/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2

---

Here is the information about my machine from "lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net", "lsmod", "nm-tool", "nmcli nm status", "iwconfig", and "rfkill list all":

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1629]

### Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1695]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

---

lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8               12557  1 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
isofs                  39815  1 
parport_pc             28152  0 
ppdev                  17073  0 
rfcomm                 42641  0 
bnep                   18036  2 
bluetooth             228619  10 bnep,rfcomm
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     36913  1 
snd_hda_codec_idt      70256  1 
joydev                 17377  0 
coretemp               13355  0 
kvm                   443165  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13259  0 
cryptd                 20373  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
snd_hda_intel          61623  1 
snd_hda_codec         136453  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
arc4                   12615  2 
snd_pcm                97451  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
hp_wmi                 18048  0 
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
sparse_keymap          13890  1 hp_wmi
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30180  1 snd_seq_midi
rtl8192ce              53594  0 
rtlwifi                79673  1 rtl8192ce
snd_seq                61554  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
wmi                    19070  1 hp_wmi
rtl8192c_common        48779  1 rtl8192ce
mac80211              606457  3 rtlwifi,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192ce
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29425  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
i915                  600351  3 
snd                    68876  10 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
uvcvideo               80847  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13056  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13202  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
cfg80211              510937  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
videobuf2_core         40513  1 uvcvideo
video                  19390  1 i915
soundcore              12680  1 snd
drm_kms_helper         49394  1 i915
videodev              129260  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
rtsx_pci_ms            13011  0 
mac_hid                13205  0 
drm                   286313  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
lpc_ich                17061  0 
psmouse                95870  0 
lp                     17759  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
memstick               16554  1 rtsx_pci_ms
mei                    41158  0 
parport                46345  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
microcode              22881  0 
serio_raw              13215  0 
ext2                   72837  1 
usb_storage            57204  1 
mmc_block              27090  0 
hid_generic            12540  0 
usbhid                 47074  0 
hid                   101002  2 hid_generic,usbhid
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         17475  0 
ahci                   25731  3 
libahci                31364  1 ahci
rtsx_pci               33355  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
r8169                  67446  0

---

nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        78:E3:B5:6D:8C:FA

  Capabilities:
  Carrier Detect:  yes
  Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
  Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
  Address:         192.168.1.73
  Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
  Gateway:         192.168.1.254

  DNS:             192.168.1.254
- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192ce
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        20:10:7A:5D:5F:EE

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
  WEP Encryption:  yes
  WPA Encryption:  yes
  WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points

---

nmcli nm status
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN
running         connected       disabled        disabled   disabled        disabled

---

iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

---

rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: hp-wwan: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

### ----------

Please help me solve this issue.  Many thanks in advance to those who may have any advice to offer.

Comment: The driver rtl8192ce already is built in to 13.04 and, as you can see in lsmod, is loaded. However, in rfkill, we see that the wireless switch or key combination is set to turn the wireless off: "1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: yes" Please turn on the switch before you proceed.

Comment: Not an expert in wifi but after I got mine installed after numerous attempts I found to activate it I had to enter in the terminal sudo modprobe rt2800 so for urcase just replace to "rt2800pci" with "rtl8192pci"

Comment: The command modprobe is a program that turns on modules in the kernel. The command would not work if you don't have the proper drivers installed.

Comment: did you solve this problem ? i have the same problem and i need a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download and try to compile this instead: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54132482/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012.zip

Extract it, then run:

```
sudo make
```

Then:

```
sudo make install
```

Then:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8792ce
```

Then check your wireless. If it still doesn't work, reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Try the later version:
 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57056576/DRIVERS/REALTEK/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012.tar.gz
but are you sure you even need to compile it?  13.04 (Raring) worked out of the box for my 8723 chip, which previously needed the compilation.  Type

```
locate rtl8723ae.ko
```

to see if the driver is present in the /lib/modules/... subdirectories.
You should see one per kernel installation.

Comment: i have the 8723 chip and i can't compile the given driver in ubuntu 13.04, it gaves me the same error messages as him, any idea what can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

[http://www.realtek.com](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=278&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true) This is a link to the manufacturer's website.
Installing rtl8192ce driver.

1 - Scroll down until you see the package for rtl8192ceVA4 or rtl8188ce. (I prefer rtl8192ceVA4 but both work fine, can't tell the difference). Download the linux driver for the newest kernel.

2 - Extract the package to your home folder. Open the folder and locate "compat-wireless-3.2.5-1.tar.bz2" package. Copy, Paste, and Extract this to your home folder as well.

3 - Open the compat-wireless-3.2.5-1 folder, locate the "udev" folder copy and paste the contents of the udev folder (firmware rules and firmware script) to your home folder then use

```
sudo nautilus
```

so you can copy paste those into

```
'/etc/udev/rules.d'

'/etc/udev/'
```

`
    '/compat-wireless-3.2.5-1/compat/scripts'

4 - Go to '~/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/compat/script/' and copy paste

"compat-install.sh" to your home folder.

5- Next, edit the makefile for compat-wireless-3.2.5-1.

```
sudo gedit ~/compat-wireless-3.2.5-1/Makefile
```

Use the "search and replace" feature on the right of the gedit toolbar to replace all instances of "(MODPROBE) -l" without quotes with "(MODPROBE)  " without quotes. The use of "-l" in this script will prevent installation and is why you get all those errors and whatnot, so get rid of it!

6 - Now run the following commands ignoring the errors as it should all work out when you are done.

```
sudo ./compat_firmware.sh

sudo ~/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/compat/3.2.5-1/scripts/unload.sh

sudo ~/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/compat/3.2.5-1/scripts/wunload.sh

sudo ~/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/compat/3.2.5-1/scripts/driver-select

sudo ./compat-install.sh

cd ~/compat-wireless-3.2.5-1

sudo su

make

make install

cd ~/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013

make

make install

sudo modprobe rtl8192ce
```

You may need to activate the hardware switch now (if you have one) but probably not.
Save any unsaved work.
Reboot.
You should have wifi now. 
This install may help the kernel driver if it does not work properly (drops out frequently). Awesome reception in Debian Weezy compared to the nonfree repository package. This works great for Ubuntustudio 12.10 as well. I've used this on Weezy, Studio, and 13.10.

Good luck!

Comment: UPDATE FOR 13.10, 13.04, and 12.04 I ran into this link that fixes all the errors and installs perfect . . . [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/352470/how-to-compile-realtek-8188ce-wireless-driver-on-ubuntu-13-04)  Awesome!

Comment: I downloaded the dependency files from the instructions and then went to the git page, grabbed a copy of the zip file, cd into the folder, sudo make, sudo make install . . . reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this thread here:
[Realtek RTL8188CE desconects randomly and features slow connections](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482564/realtek-rtl8188ce-desconects-randomly-and-features-slow-connections)

I have the rtl8188CE device and use the rtl8192ce driver as well.  I was having disconnection issues and tried that thread.  Connection has been strong and solid ever since following those instructions.  Granted that I am using Ubuntu 14.04, but according to the bug report, this drive has issues with numerous kernels and this is the fix suggested there.