# problems after upgrading to 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, upgrade

I am having some problems after upgrading to 12.04LTS.

Wireless now won't connect, Wireless adapter shows as unclaimed.

```
sudo lshw -C network shows

    liz@liz-N220:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for liz: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8192E/RTL8192SE Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0100000-f0103fff
```

I have performed `sudo apt-get dist upgrade` and have updated drivers through Ubuntu but all to no avail.

---

Here is the output of `dpkg -S rtl* | grep /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/` as requested in the comments:

```
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192se/rtl8192se.ko
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8180
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/rtl8150.ko
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192ce
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192de
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/rtl8187.ko
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.ko
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192se
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8180/rtl8180.ko
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192c
linux-image-3.2.0-41-generic: /lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192de/rtl8192de.ko
```

after entering still shows unclaimed

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8192E/RTL8192SE Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0100000-f0103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:24:54:43:8b:92
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.88 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:45 memory:f0200000-f0203fff ioport:3000(size=256)
```

Comment: any help much apreciated

Answer (score 0):

*The below answer is copied from my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/294066/52726). However, the person still has not marked it as the correct answer.*

Okay, we'll have to manually download the driver for your wireless card and install it.

#### Step 1

Download [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54132482/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012.zip), and save it to your Downloads folder

#### Step 2

Open up a terminal. To do so, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Type in the following commands and hit enter, one by one.

```
cd ~/Downloads
unzip rtl*
cd rtl*
```

#### Step 3

Enter the following:

```
sudo make
```

If the output from this command gives you lines that mention an error, like this:

```
make[1]: ***[_module_/home/alaa/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012] Error 2 
make[1]: Leaving directory/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
make: * [all] Error 2
```

...then stop here, and let us know. But if it does not give you lines that contain the word "error", type the following command:

```
sudo make install
```

#### Step 4

Once that is done, enter the following command:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8192se
```

You should not get any output here (if you do, just ignore it). Check if your wireless is working. If it isn't, reboot your computer.

Comment: have done all this and no joy im afraid

Comment: The newer version of the file is recommended. Here is a link from my Dropbox. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58267392/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012.tar.gz  Please try again.

Comment: Hi my son, who knows what he is doing hsa been dealing with this but has now gone. i am a complete novice. can you please guide me through what i have to do with this info. thanks

Comment: Follow the steps in my answer. Also, the file mentioned in my answer is a modified one that should work. Or, you can use the file mentioned in the comment by @chili555.

Comment: HI have tried again, no error messages but still does not find any wireless networks

Comment: That's odd. You rebooted, right? Can you edit your question to include the output of the following command: `lsmod | grep rtl`.

Comment: And also, the output of this command: `dpkg -S rtl* | grep /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/`.

Comment: yes re booted  do i just type lsmod grep rtl into terminal?

Comment: have managed to do second one

Comment: It's `lsmod | grep rtl`. The symbol after lsmod is Shift+\ (shift backslash), usually next to the Enter key.

Comment: nothing happens when i input this???

Comment: Okay. Try the command `sudo modprobe rtl8192se`, and enter your password when asked. You shouldn't see any output. If you do, tell us what it is. If you don't, check if your wireless is working (also check if it still says UNCLAIMED in `sudo lshw -C network`). Also, in your previous comment you said "doesn't find any wireless networks"? Do you mean that it's working but it can't find WiFi networks? Or did you mean the wireless card is not working, and is still showing "UNCLAIMED" as in your original question?

Comment: wireless not working . it does not even try to search for networks although previously used ones are showing. it does not say unclaimed but PCI (sysfs) if you run your command?????

Comment: No just give the command some time, it will show the output. Anyways, I think I have found the problem. Delete the files and folders that you downloaded in your Downloads folder (everything that start with "rtl"). Download the file that @chili555 posted (in the second comment here) to your Downloads folder. Follow the steps in my answer (Step 1 to Step 4), and hopefully it should work.

Comment: If, in the end, it does not work, show us the output of `dmesg | grep 819`.

Comment: have downloaded chili555 file. says its not a zip file. the command cd rtl* does not work either???

Comment: Download the file to your desktop. Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' It will extract it no matter what it is. Then do: cd Desktop/rtl* and continue on as above.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, my bad, chili's file is a different format. You could follow what chili said, or replace the command `unzip rtl*` in my answer with `tar -xzf rtl*` and continue. Also, since this discussion is turning into a long one, there is one solution, though I don't know if it's fine with you: upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04. This latest version of Ubuntu already supports this driver without installing any extra stuff (correct me if I'm wrong @chili555), so it should directly work if you upgrade to 13.04.

Comment: Quite correct. You may or may not need to install extra firmware, a quite easy task.

Comment: is the fact that 13.04 is unsupported gong to be a problem

Comment: No no. Ubuntu 13.04 is not "unsupported", it **is supported** for 9 months. Every Ubuntu version is supported. LTS (long term support) versions, which come out every two years, provide 5 years of support, instead of the usual 9 months. This "support" basically means security enhancements, compatibility with new hardware, and so on. In my opinion, it is more for people that use Ubuntu to run servers (for example, run a website). But the average user should not worry about this, you will not be getting anything "less" from the normal versions.

Comment: Can you move this to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new)?

Comment: I tried, but the user has less than 20 reputation.